# wso2 esb bam server profile in governance registry

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam, wso2-esb

Is there any way to store BAM server profile and stream definition under governance registry, so that it can be added once in ESB master node and made available to other ESB slave nodes ? Currently, looks like it is stored under configuration registry only.
FYI - We have mounted all ESB nodes to one Governance registry. Only master node has write permission to registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is the correct way. By default BAM server profiles and stream configurations are designed only to be stored in config registry. It is not possible to store in governance registry. In future releases we will store all configurations in a deployable artifact which will easily deployment synchronized over other nodes.

Comment: Thanks for response. Is there anyway to add BAM server profile/stream definition on master node and access from slave nodes ?

Comment: Only current option is registry mounting. Point all slave nodes to the master node's config registry. http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2010/04/sharing-registry-space-across-multiple-product-instances will help you.